# Using Jquery Ajax success handler

Tags: jquery, ajax

I just discovered there is a Ajax success handler, which is great because its automated! but I'm unsure if it is suitable for my use-case.

I'm making many ajax calls and mostly programatically (without user clicks etc) so I don't really want to bind functions to a html element.

This is how I'm doing things ATM but I'd like to automate the process. 
The key thing is that the method must get called before everything else and if I catch something then I don't want execution in my response handler to execute.

```
function GetSomeData() {     
$.getJSON("/ajax/getsomedata",GetSomeDataResponse);
}
function GetSomeDataResponse(response){
    if(DoesServerResponseIndicateError(response)) {
        //Continue
    }
}
function DoesServerResponseIndicateError() {
//see if it contains any custom errors, if it does, Don't execute the //continue block
}
```

Comment: What is your question?  I see no issues with what you have so far.  What did you try?  What problems did you have?

Comment: the problem is, that I have call this inside every ajax success handler which isn't very DRY, and its slightly verbose. It works fine though justlooking for a nier solution :)

Comment: You can put all the common code in a function that you just pass the URL and your success callback to so that all the server response parsing is DRY in one function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to automate error handling, I would look at the [jQuery.ajaxError](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) function that exists for this purpose.  It's a global handler that will work for all ajax requests you make anywhere on the page.

Or to make it more fine-grained, there's an `error` callback you can use with individual calls.

Trying to surmise whether the data in a *successful* ajax call indicates and error will be very difficult and counterproductive.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I'm doing the frontend and my partner is doing the JSP code, which uses JSONResoultion to respond rather than an actual Server error so jQuery won't identify it as an error. I've already setup an errorhandler to handle actual 404 errors etc but as the error response comes back in JSON format, I think I need to do custom processing.

Comment: I also have another issue, where if my users click too soon, then the server won't actually respond to the ajax calls in time and I get a 404. So I might look at putting a timeout function on every ajax call before it actually sends the request, which is another use-case for automating logic inside the ajax life cycle

Comment: @Baconbeastnz - then that should work.  Of course your `DoesServerResponseIndicateError` will need a parameter, for the data returned, but yeah, just check the data for the error code, and use your global error handler for 404s and such.

Comment: @Baconbeastnz Not sure about the click too soon problem.  You might want to ask a new question and really explain it well, since I don't follow.

Comment: Isn't the point of on success to fire only on success? You can second that with a response in your Json reply to be sure

Comment: @Michael - yes, success only fires when the ajax response is successful.  But you're sending back error codes in successfully completed ajax calls, so you'll need to check for errors there.